# Correct usage of JQuery's prepend(...) function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't figure out what's going wrong here. I'm using a CMS that spits the content of a field into a certain place on the page that is different from where the customer wants it to be. So as a workaround I am using `JQuery` to reroute that piece of content to where I need it:

```
var calcUrBennies = $("div.stl-gift-illustrator-row h3").text();
$("div#calc-benefits-right-wrapper").prepend(calcUrBennies); 
$(document).ready(function(){$("div.stl-gift-illustrator-row h3").hide();});
```

That puts the inner text where needs to be; however, I need the `calcUrBennies` string to be inside `h3` tags. I tried changing the second line to

```
$("div#calc-benefits-right-wrapper").prepend("<h3>"+calcUrBennies+"</h3>");
```

but that didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Adding the `h3` tags should work just fine, did you try actually putting your code *inside* the document ready handler? And remove the tagNames, ID's are unique.

Comment: Side note: Unless it's possible you'll have an `id="calc-benefits-right-wrapper"` element that *isn't* a `div` sometimes and you want this code to ignore it if so, the `div` in `$("div#calc-benefits-right-wrapper")` is not only pointless, but significantly degrading the performance of that line of code. If it's a one-off, it's harmless, but in general qualifying `id` selectors is an anti-pattern barring very specific (and unusual) use cases.

Comment: Does `$("div.stl-gift-illustrator-row h3").hide();` affect the `"<h3>"+calcUrBennies+"</h3>"`? Notice the `h3`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue of running this code before the document is ready. If you are simply wanting to move that element, you can select it then move the whole thing to another part of the dom.

Something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var calcUrBennies = $("div.stl-gift-illustrator-row h3");
    $("div#calc-benefits-right-wrapper").prepend(calcUrBennies);
});
```

this will move the whole h3. It does wait until the page has been loaded, though, so there might be some flicker. You could probably work that out a different way or try it before the ready event fires.

Comment: The OP said that the code they quoted moves the *text*, so apparently it isn't a `ready` issue.

Answer (score 0):

> ...however, I need the calcUrBennies string to be inside h3 tags. I tried changing the second line to

As the text is *already* in `h3` tags, why not just move them?

```
var calcUrBennies = $("div.stl-gift-illustrator-row h3"); // <== No `.text()`
$("div#calc-benefits-right-wrapper").prepend(calcUrBennies); 
// No line here using `hide` on the `h3`s
```

You've said your existing code successfully moves the text, but without the `h3` elements, so I assume you don't need the `ready` wrapper (e.g., your code is in a `script` tag **after** the elements it refers to in the HTML, which is totally fine). But just in case, if the elements don't exist at that time, you'd wrap all of the code in the `ready` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var calcUrBennies = $("div.stl-gift-illustrator-row h3"); // <== No `.text()`
    $("div#calc-benefits-right-wrapper").prepend(calcUrBennies); 
    // No line here using `hide` on the `h3`s
});
```

But again, you've said your existing code moved the text, so you shouldn't need that.